# Add active class to LI element in audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio-player

I'm working on my audio player and I have come to the part where I want to add an active class to whichever song is currently playing. However I am sort of confused because I can't seem to properly hook the current song playing after the song ended in my ul( the li's).

This is a link to my private domain so you can get a clearer idea. I hope it's not considered advertising, I don't have anything on the domain but my tests and projects: [***Link***](http://simeriaionut.com/carols/)

So everytime you click a song, the LI get's a class of "active", however if the song ends, the following song doesn't have a class of "active"

[***JSFiddle HERE***](http://jsfiddle.net/mjy8dayp/1/)

Okay, if it is of help, I'm going to add the end of track function here:

```
// Events linstener
audio.addEventListener("ended", function() { switchTrack(); });

// Functions
function switchTrack(event){
    $("ul li").removeClass('active');
    if(index == (obj.songsrc.length - 1)){
        index = 0;
    } else {
        index++;    
    }
    playlist_status.innerHTML = obj.title[index];
    playlist_song.innerHTML = obj.songs[index];
    playlist_coverimage.src = "images/"+obj.images[index]+".jpg";
    audio.src = dir+obj.songsrc[index]+ext;
    audio.play();
}
```

And this is how I create the LI's:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.songsrc.length; i++) {
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "songs_wrap";
    li.innerHTML = "<div class='songs_inner'>" + "<h4>"+obj.title[i]+ "</h4><p>" + obj.songs[i] + "</p></div>";
    mylist.appendChild(li);
    if(audio.play)
    $("li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: The line with the 'if(audio.play)' is missing an opeining bracket.  It should be : `if(audio.play) {
    $("li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");}`

Comment: That's right, but it still behaves like it should. The problem is in the switchTrack function, where I should add the active class to the current LI playing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a listener to you audio object.

`audio.addEventListener('ended', function(e) { // do some class swapping });`

Or something along those lines with [Media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events).

Comment: I forgot to add it here, however it was added in my code. So the function behaves as it should, everything works fine except for the active class being activated on the LI that is currently playing. Please take a look at the link.

Comment: Do you have a bit more code you could share so it's easier to see what you have already? Maybe in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Done, added the JSFiddle

Comment: Is this too complicated or did I addressed my question wrong?